# Fixed-point iterations for quadratic function $x\mapsto x^2-2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f(x)$ be $x^2-x-2$.  I want to find the root using FPI in an interval where it will converge.  I have chosen $g(x)=x^2-2$ and so $g'(x)=2x$.  The convergence condition, $|g'(x)|<1$ is obviously satisfied in $-0.5<x<0.5$.

**Problem:** I have failed to find a consistent interval outside of this convergence interval up to $\pm 1$ for which the iteration consistently diverges.

**Question:** Does this convergence condition only guarantee convergence (in the bounds) but not divergence (outside the bounds)?

Comment: Is that fixed-point iteration fixed? From $x^2=2+x$ one finds the better iteration $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+x_n}$ for the positive root.

Comment: Yes, but I thought the reason it’s ‘better’ is because it satisfies abs(g’(x))<1 in some interval.  But g(x) in op works just fine up to -+1.

Comment: $g(x)=\sqrt{2+x}$ has $g'(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt{2+x}}\le\frac25$ for all $x>0$, $g(x)=1+\frac2x$ has $g'(x)=-\frac{2}{x^2}>-1$ for $x>\frac32$, so you get intervals with $|g'(x)|<1$ for many fixed-point functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us consider the fixed point iterations associated to the function $g: x \mapsto x^2-2$, defined by the quadratic map
$$
x_{n+1} = {x_n}^2 - 2, \qquad x_0 \in \Bbb R .
$$
This map has many [periodic points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_points_of_complex_quadratic_mappings#Cycles_for_period_greater_than_2), even with large period. The period-one fixed points $-1$, $2$ are both repelling fixed points (indices $2>1$ and $4>1$, respectively). Thus, fixed-point iterations will not converge towards these values unless the starting value $x_0$ is exactly equal to $-1$ or $2$. Setting
$y_n = -\frac{1}{4} x_n + \frac{1}{2}$, the logistic map $y_{n+1} = r y_n (1-y_n)$ with parameter $r=4$ is obtained,
which exact [solution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html) is
bounded and exhibits chaotic behavior (see also [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Solution_when_r_=_4)). Therefore,
$$
x_n = 2\cos\left(2^n\cos^{-1}(x_0/2)\right) 
$$
is bounded and exhibits chaotic behavior too (the sequence does not diverge to infinity).